# add additional cells to the bottom ofUICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

Im using UICollectionView to get a set of images from instagram however i want to load past images when i get to the bottom of the page. I do however recieve the past images because they are logged into the console but dont appear on the screen.

**Here is my code to retrieve the images:**

```
- (void)nextInstagramPage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
NSDictionary *page = self.timelineResponse[@"pagination"];
NSString *nextPage = page[@"next_url"];

[[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextPage] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    self.timelineResponse = responseObject;
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];

}
```

**Here is my code to detect when the user gets to the bottom of the screen:**

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

[self nextInstagramPage:indexPath];

}
```

***Edit***: I have found out that the collectionview is a subclass of uiscrollview so how would i correctly implement a method which has an indexpath to detect the bottom of the scrollview!

Comment: are you sure "didEndDisplayingCell" does that? it sounds like that method is called when an item moves off the screen...

Comment: when that method is called then you can test to see if the last cell in your collection view is part of the visibleCells array property of the collection view.

Comment: that method (in the documentation) is said to "Use this method to detect when a cell is removed from a collection view, as opposed to monitoring the view itself to see when it appears or disappears." so this is probably called when the cell is no longer allocated, aka it was dequeued.

Comment: put a test with in collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath: and when you allocated the last cell then call your method to show more pictures

Comment: could you show a complete example as a answer please?

Answer (score 0):

With in your code i am making 2 assumptions, that you have an array of data to run parallel with your ui collection view and the delegate/datasource methods. you would notice at least these two methods in your code.

```
– collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:
– collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:
```

the first one tells you how many items/cells/squares you see in your ui collection view, the second makes you create what the item/cell/square will look like.

In the first method you told the uicolelction view how many there were, with in the cellforitem you should test "is this the last image" if it is the last image then download more images, if it is not the last image then continue as if nothing happened

Edit:

```
[[self entries] count]
```

you had that, now with in cell for row at index path do

```
if ( indexpath.item == ([[self entries] count] - 1) ) {
   // download more data and add it to the 'entries' array
}
```

Comment: how would i add an object; i know we do add object on the mutable array, but my response object which contains the data is in a different method

Comment: - (void)nextInstagramPage:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *page = self.timelineResponse[@"pagination"];
    NSString *nextPage = page[@"next_url"];
    
    [[InstagramClient sharedClient] getPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",nextPage] parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.timelineResponse = responseObject;
        [self.collectionView reloadData];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Failure: %@", error);
}];
}